# Leave space at the top of every printed page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

So, I have a header that needs to appear at the top of every page when the user prints this website. I'm setting position to fixed to get it to appear at the top of every page, but the problem is that the header is now overlapping some of the content near the top. The header is a static size, so if I could just put a margin X number of pixels at the top of every page that would solve my problem, but I can't find a way to do that. Thanks.

Example code:
HTML

```
<header>This should be at the top of every printed page</header>
<section id="content">*Multiple pages of text*</section>
```

CSS

```
header {
position:fixed;
top:-10;
height:20px;
}

#content {
left:0px;
overflow:visible;
position:relative;
/*top:52px;*/
width:98%;
}
```

The "top:52px" worked to get the content to avoid the header, but it was also causing some lines of text to be cut off in the middle by a page break, which is why it's commented out.

New info:
Something interesting I discovered about the "top:52px" line: it's not actually moving the content down 52 pixels, it's somehow hiding the top 52px of content on every page. I noticed this when I set header display to none and noticed significant portions of my content still missing.

Note: I'm open to javascript or jquery solutions if one exists.

Comment: Please provide some example code showing what you've tried so far. Are you using a css style sheet or doing this inline?

Comment: Added example code. I have a print stylesheet.

Comment: Somewhat solved:
I set the display value of #content to "table-cell" and set top and bottom padding. This causes it to leave space at the top and bottom of every page. Nearly perfect. The problem is now that apparently "table-cell" elements don't listen to any width settings and I have content disappearing off the right edge of the page. So close, so close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out:

```
#content {
   position:relative;
   display:table;
   table-layout:fixed;
   padding-top:20px;
   padding-bottom:20px;
   width: 94%;
   height:auto;
}
```

This puts padding at the top and bottom of every page, does not cut any content off from the top or bottom, and allows #content to respect width adjustments so that content doesn't get cut off on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different ways to do this, one quick way would be to just use a div tag and set the margin-top to however many pixels you want:

```
<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>
```

Comment: Tried this, and only the first page has the margin.

Answer (score 0):

simply add to #content:

```
#content {
    margin-top: 50px; // however many pixels you need
}
```

Comment: This is only working on the first page of the print. Every other page the content bumps right up to the top. I'm targeting Firefox 17 if that makes a difference.

Comment: If that is the case, have you checked that all the other pages' content is wrapped with the #content id?

Comment: Yep, it is. Something interesting I discovered about the "top:52px" line: it's not actually moving the content down 52 pixels, it's somehow hiding the top 52px of content on every page. I noticed this when I set header display to none and noticed significant portions of my content still missing. I'm adding this new info to the OP too.

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle I could probably help you out a lot more than just making suggestions and seeing if they work. I suspect it has something to do with your use of the `position` and `top` properties.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K4ENQ/3/


I can't figure how to simulate print with jsfiddle, but there it is. Thanks.

Comment: The reason the header is only showing up once is because it is only included once in the HTML. You could consider determining the breakpoints for each page when printing and inserting your `<header>` at those breakpoints in the HTML.

Comment: It shows up once on screen, which is what we want. But it shows up at the top of every page if you go print the HTML (I have no idea why this behavior is so), which is also what we want. What we don't want is the header overlapping the top content when you print it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about CSS *@media print* and *@page rule margin property* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Getting_Started/Media).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only added a padding-top: XXpx and that was it. The css worked fine in all pages